# Camera position and rotation while following path

Tags: animation, camera, path

I have a camera following a path, by using the "ctrl+p -> follow path" method. I noticed that during the animation, the camera position and rotation shown are constant (they are the ones the camera has at the start of the path). I actually need the camera position and orientation for every frame of the path. Is there a way to obtain that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bake the animation and clear parent to get the transform data of the camera.

Select the camera, and in **Object** menu select **Animation>Bake Action**

[image]

Then in **Bake Action** menu enable **Visual Keying** and **Clear Parents**.

That will bake the location and rotation of the camera for every frame into an action.

[image]